# Set monitor refresh rate to 144Hz

Tags: display

I have a laptop with Intel HD Graphics 630 and NVIDIA GeForce 1050Ti (Intel i7-7700HQ) and a Samsung C27JG5x 144Hz display but I cannot set it to work with 144Hz refresh rate. In the Windows settings I can only set it to 59Hz or 60Hz. It also says that the display is connected to Intel graphics insted of NVIDIA.

Comment: When I disabled the Intel graphics, it have switched to Microsoft Basic Display Adapter

Comment: On a laptop you may be limited to what the integrated graphics supports

Comment: @flolilo It's a laptop. The display output is likely hardwired to the integrated GPU. Models with outputs connected to dGPU are quite rare and ones where you can disable iGPU completely are even harder to find, I haven't heard about one manufactured in the last 6 years.

Comment: So it may not be possible to set 144Hz refresh rate for exteranl display?

Comment: @michalt38 Depends if your iGPU and outputs support it. What laptop is this?